# CREATE and UPDATE operations in parallel processing using CRUD Repository

Tags: sql, spring, hibernate, spring-boot, spring-data-jpa

I am designing an application where I get two events from the upstream system i.e. **CREATE** and **UPDATE**. Now, consider the following Events:-

```
 1. CREATE User [id=1, name=Ram, city=Delhi, email=abc@gmail.com, phone=12345]
 2. UPDATE User [id=1, city=Mumbai, phone=56789]
```

Since the application involves parallel processing, therefore the order of the event is not guaranteed and hence the UPDATE event might come before the CREATE event.

## If UPDATE operation comes first followed by CREATE operation

For an UPDATE operation, this is what is stored in the database:-

```
    [id=1, name=null, city=Mumbai, email=null, phone=56789]
```

However, when I perform the CREATE operation, the updated fields are replaced by the old values and this is what gets stored in the database

```
    [id=1, name=Ram, city=Delhi, email=abc@gmail.com, phone=12345]
```

But I wanted only the values which were *null* after the first **UPDATE operation** to be inserted while performing the **CREATE operation**. But the **CREATE operation** overwrites the updated fields and hence the updates are lost. So basically, this is what I am expecting as output after both **UPDATE** and **INSERT operations**:-

```
[id=1, name=Ram, city=Mumbai, email=abc@gmail.com, phone=56789]
```

---

> My question is that how do I achieve this ?
>
> **Note:** I am using *CRUD Repository* and prefer a solution which uses CRUD Repository only for database operations.

---

---

Here is the code snippet :-

1. Entity Class:-

   ```
   @Entity
   public class User {

   @Id
   private Integer id;
   private String name;
   private String city;
   private String email;
   private String phone;

   //Setters and Getters 
   }
   ```
2. Repository:-

   ```
   import org.springframework.data.repository.CrudRepository;
   import com.therealdanvega.domain.User;

   public interface UserRepository extends CrudRepository<User, Integer>{

   }
   ```
3. Application Class :-

   ```
       @SpringBootApplication
       public class JsontodbApplication implements CommandLineRunner {

       @Autowired
       private UserRepository userRepo;

       public static void main(String[] args) {
           SpringApplication.run(JsontodbApplication.class, args);
       }

       @Override
       public void run(String... args) throws Exception {

           /* UPDATE USER */
           User user = userRepo.save(updateUser(new User()));
           System.out.println(userRepo.findOne(1));  //[id=1, name=null, city=Mumbai, email=null, phone=56789]

           /* CREATE USER */
           userRepo.save(updateUser(user));
           System.out.println(userRepo.findOne(1)); //[id=1, name=Ram, city=Delhi, email=abc@gmail.com, phone=12345]

       }

       public User createUser(User user) {
           user.setId(1);
           user.setName("Ram");
           user.setCity("Delhi");
           user.setEmail("abc@gmail.com");
           user.setPhone("12345");
           return user;
       }

       public User updateUser(User user) {
           user.setId(1);
           user.setCity("Mumbai");
           user.setPhone("56789");
           return user;
           }
       }
   ```

Comment: You create a RestController class and create a two method and map with PostMapping & PutMapping.

Comment: https://spring.io/guides/tutorials/bookmarks/

Answer (score 0):

Since Java 8 it has been possible to add default methods to interfaces. You could add a default method to your `UserRepository` like:

```
default <S extends User> S safeSave(S entity) {
    // your checks and entity manipulation, like:
    // check if exists already and fill fields accordingly
    // finally save the correct data
    return save(entity);
}
```